# Physical location of my Heroku addon

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm writing my own Add-on, e.g. a custom database. But where should I physically allocate my database instances? I'd like to make them geographically close to the requesting application. I see the provisioning call specifies an Amazon region (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-provider-api#provision). 
So is this the recommendation - install my database on Amazon EC2 on various regions?

Or is there a way to make it even closer, either geographically (e.g. same Amazon Availability Zone) or in terms of security (e.g. same DNS domain, or same IP subnet).

In this context, I checked out Heroku Postgres addon, and noticed their database security manages to distinguish between "local connections" (from the Heroku application) and "remote connections" (from my developer PC). So what is "local" - same Amazon region? Or did they manage to use the same DNS domain, IP subnet, etc?
See here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#remote-connections

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same ec2 region is fine. Heroku apps move across all AZs in a given region. Every time a dyno starts it may or may not be in a different AZ than the last time it ran.